Relative vs. absolute error bars in log-scaled plots
There's conflicting info from seemingly knowledgeable sources about the correct way to show error bars on a log-scaled plot.

$log_{10}(x \pm \Delta x)$ shows the absolute error. On the one hand, it's readily interpretable: if we know with some probability that $x$ is within $\vert x - \Delta x, x + \Delta x \vert$, that probability doesn't change after a log transformation. We can read the tick marks and readily understand the interval. On the other hand, as $\Delta x$ approaches $x$, the error bars appear asymmetric, which various sources say is bad (sometimes without explanation, sometimes because it visually implies a greater probability that the value is below the mean than above it). For $\Delta x \ge x$ the lower error bar segment would extend off the plot.

$x \pm \frac{\Delta x}{x \ln 10}$ shows the relative error using propagation of uncertainty. The error bars are visually symmetric. But I don't understand how you're supposed to interpret the lengths when read against the tick marks.


For example:

Here, $x = 8000$ and $\Delta x = 7000$ for the first point (blue), and $x = 5000$ and $\Delta x = 500$ for the second (yellow). When $\Delta x \ll x$ (yellow), the two methods are basically indistinguishable. When $\Delta x \approx x$ (blue), the bar appears to range from 3,335 to 19,190. How are you supposed to interpret those numbers?
What's the correct approach to showing error bars, and why?

Various sources:

Eric Stuve's lecture
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95254/31907 (note that I'm also confused by the second answer there per my comment on it)
Relative error on a log-log plot


Not really an answer to the question, but: (1) Symmetry of error bars is not always a desirable property. Consider a bounded variable for example, where a symmetric interval can exceed the range of possible values. (2) None of these methods give you a range with a known probability to contain the true value, you would need a Bayesian credible interval for that. (3) The answers to the quoted question also say this is just a Taylor approximation and only works when $\Delta x \ll x$.

In the log scale I usually prefer geometric means and geometric standard errors. The latter are multiplicative and thereby symmetric in that scale. Their interpretation is similar to the regular SD/SE which was now calculated on the logs: you expect 68% of your (log-normal) population to fall within $(\mu\div\sigma,\ \mu\times\sigma)$, with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ the geometric parameters.

The role of an error bar is to communicate information regarding variability to the person viewing the graph and so the 'right' approach is the one that most successfully communicates. In that regard the ideal style of error bars with log scales depends on the rationale for the logarithm.
Some measurements are naturally and conventionally made on a logarithmic scale. For example, acidity on the pH scale, and drug potency on the log concentration scale or affinity scale (I leave it as an exercise for the reader to find equivalent examples in their own area of expertise.) For those measurements it is typically the log values that are recorded and thus the variability of those log values is what the error bars should communicate. Those error bars would usually be symmetrical.
In some cases it is helpful to use a logarithmic axis on a graph in order to be able to display very small and very large values at equivalent detail even where those values are more naturally interpreted on a linear scale. In such a case asymmetrical error bars would communicate the relevant variability better than symmetrical bars.

Of the examples posted by ZachB, the rightmost one is correct. (The left one too, but then it's not a log scale.) The relative error is the absolute error on a log scale. My comment about avoiding asymmetric error bars is that, absent any other information to the contrary, asymmetric error bars are a dead giveaway that the error bars were plotted incorrectly (which is the middle example).
My derivation assumes that a differential error ($\Delta x$) can be approximated by a differential error ($dx$). That obviously will not work for very large differential errors. I defer to Frans Rodenburg and PBulls for more detailed treatments.
FWIW, my lecture is based on material in "Experimentation: An Introduction to Measurement Theory and Experiment Design" by D. C. Baird (Prentice Hall, 1962). It's a wonderful little book dealing with experiments in physics and chemistry. If you can find a copy, it's worth adding to your collection.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks for the reply. I'm still not sure why it's (more) useful to have the error bars on the right, or why asymmetric error bars are objectively incorrect. To obtain the RSD, you need to somewhat tediously calculate $log \left(\frac{top}{mid}\right)$, and multiply by $mid$ to obtain the absolute SD. In the middle plot, the SD is just $top - mid$.
